# UIScrollView cannot scroll horizontally

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView inside a UIViewController and I expect it to be scrolled horizontally. I programmatically add button to the ScrollView by a loop. After the loop, I set the `myScrollView.contentSize.width` to be `buttonWidth * numberOfButtons`. I also double check to make sure that contentSize is bigger than the scrollview's frame (in this case the scrollview has width of 375).

```
let numberOfButton = 7        
for index in 0..<numberOfButton {
    let button = UIButton()
    let frame = CGRect(x: 80 + (index * 80), y: 6, width: 60, height: 32)
    button.setTitle("Button" + String(index), forState: .Normal)
    button.frame = frame
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Museo Sans", size: 16)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: .Normal) 

    myScrollView.addSubview(button)
}
myScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 100*numberOfButtons, height: 42)
```

When I run the code, it only appears to the Button3 (there are 7 buttons) and I cannot scroll it to the end. However, when I set `myScrollView.bounces = true` I can drag the scrollview around and see other buttons but it will bounce back to the original state. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: IMO you should use a collectionview instead? Also, what is the value of myScrollView.contentSize after this. Can you print it to see

Comment: myScrollView.frame (0.0, 60.0, 375.0, 42.0)  / myScrollView.contentSize (700.0, 42.0)

Comment: The content seems to ok then, the only other thing I can think of is maybe enabling the scroll. Add in myScrollView.isScrollEnabled = true

Comment: well, actually it can be scrolled but just little. Even though I still have 3 or 4 more buttons, I cannot scroll to them.

Comment: Ah ok, Well let me get this straight, You want to display 6 buttons right. As your going < numberOfButton which will stop at 6. Also it must be a typo but you have an s at the end of numberOfButton when computing the contentSize. In any case, I think your problem is the fact your already using up 80points on the x axis on the first button. Causing the others to be off screen. Change the line where you set the frame to this: let frame = CGRect(x: 8 + (index * 96), y: 6, width: 80, height: 32). Ive added this as an answer so you can accept if it fixes you're issue

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is setting the X value on the first button. I have just tried this code and it works fine

```
    let numberOfButtons = 7
    for index in 0..<numberOfButtons {
        let button = UIButton()
        let frame = CGRect(x: 8 + (index * 96), y: 6, width: 80, height: 32)
        button.setTitle("Button \(index)", for: .normal)
        button.frame = frame
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Museo Sans", size: 16)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: .normal)

        myScrollView.addSubview(button)
    }
    myScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 100*numberOfButton, height: 42)
```

Comment: I have solved the problem. This happens because I have a default button (just the first one, others get created dynamically) in the XIB and it has constraint with parent view, that's why I cannot scroll out of the first button. I have read your comment and solution. Even though they did not answer the question, but they give me a clue to solve this. Thank you very much.

Comment: Ah, I would try and avoid having both static and dynamic views. It could get very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
tagBar.contentSize = CGSize(width: 100*7, height: 42)
```

to

```
myScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 100*7, height: 42)
```

Comment: Actually, it's just a typo mistake. I just edited my code. Problem remains the same

Answer (score 0):

The answer that Rajeshkumar R gave you, or better use constraints. You can set a constraint between the left of `myScrollView` and the left your first button (a "leading space" constraint), then a leading space constraint between each button and the previous one, and when you finish looping, a trailing space from your last button to the `myScrollView`.

This way you don't have to calculate the contentSize yourself. It's also more extensible (for example, if you had buttons of different sizes, you would have to know each width, sum them all, then sum the margins between elements and between the first and the last one with the scrollView…).